# Explaining Simple Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I successfully wrote a for loop in R. That is okay and I am very happy that it works. But I also want to understand what I've done exactly because I will have to work with loops later on in my analysis as well.

I work with Raster Data (DEMs). I load them into the environment as rasters and then I use the getValues function in the loop as I want to do some calculations. Looks as follows:

```
list <- dir(pattern=".tif", full.names=T)
tif.files <- list()
tif.files.values <- tif.files

for (i in 1: length(list)){
    tif.files[[i]] <- raster (list[[i]])
    tif.files.values[[i]] <- getValues(tif.files[[i]])
}
```

Okay, so far so good. I don't get why I have to specify tif.files and tif.files.values before I use them in the loop and I don't know why to specify them exactly how I did that. For the first part, the raster operation, I had a pattern. Maybe someone can explain the context. I really want to understand R.

Comment: You successfully wrote a for-loop, or you successfully copied someone else's code and you aren't sure why it works?

Comment: I had a course last semester and I want to simplify the things as I now have not only one DEM but a list of 6.

Comment: I haven't used `R`, but essentially, you need to create structures, initialize them, and do something with the values. I found this, which seems to explain everything fairly well: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-on-loops-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
tif.files[[i]] <- raster (list[[i]])
```

then `tif.files[[i]]` is the result of running `raster(list[[i]])`, so that is storing the **raster object**. This object contains the metadata (extent, number of rows, cols etc) and the data, although if the tiff is huge it doesn't actually read it in at the time.

```
tif.files.values[[i]] <- getValues(tif.files[[i]])
```

that line calls `getValues` on the **raster object**, which reads the values from the raster and returns a vector. The values of the grid cells are now in `tif.files.values[[i]]`.

Experiment by printing `tif.files[[1]]` and `tif.files.values[[1]]` at the R prompt.

## Note

This is R, not RStudio, which is the interface you are using that has all the buttons and menus. The R language exists quite happily without it, and your question is just a language question. I've edited and tagged it now for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is really helpful! :)